# Problem with ag-grid cell editor based on React Component connected to Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a problem with custom ag-grid cell editor. I want to get state from Redux but if I use connect function from 'react-redux' it hides *isPopup* function which is needed by ag-grid. In result my editor is not visible outside of editing cell.

```
class SelectEditor extends React.Component {
  getValue = () => '123'
  isPopup = () => true

  render() {
    const unselected = { border: '1px solid transparent', padding: 4 };
    const selected = { border: '1px solid lightgreen', padding: 4 };

    const happyStyle = this.props.happy ? selected : unselected;
    const sadStyle = !this.props.happy ? selected : unselected;
    return (
      <div ref='container'>
        <img src='https://www.ag-grid.com/images/smiley.png' style={happyStyle} />
        <img src='https://www.ag-grid.com/images/smiley-sad.png' style={sadStyle} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ happy: state.clientsData });
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({});

// 1) popup works - I see component
export default SelectEditor;
// 2) popup doesn't work
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SelectEditor);
```

Any ideas how to create proper component?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? facing the same issue since one month. Any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Actually `ag-grid` uses instance of class components to hook any life cycle methods, which in your case it can't get instance of `SelectEditor` as it is wrapped with `connect` HoC.

```
const SelectEditor = (props) => {
  const getValue = () => '123'
  const isPopup = () => true
  React.useImperativeHandle(props.innerRef, () => ({ getValue, isPopup }))

  const unselected = { border: '1px solid transparent', padding: 4 };
  const selected = { border: '1px solid lightgreen', padding: 4 };
  const happyStyle = this.props.happy ? selected : unselected;
  const sadStyle = !this.props.happy ? selected : unselected;

  return (
    <div ref='container'>
      <img src='https://www.ag-grid.com/images/smiley.png' style={happyStyle} />
      <img src='https://www.ag-grid.com/images/smiley-sad.png' style={sadStyle} />
    </div>
  );
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ happy: state.clientsData });
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({});

const ConnectedSelect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SelectEditor)

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <ConnectedSelect innerRef={ref} {...props} />);
```

I'm not sure if `ag-grid` uses refs in case of class components as well, but you can try that as well. If it works then you won't have to convert class to functional component.